# FOSUserBundle + verify user related properties after valid login

Tags: fosuserbundle

I have implemented the FOSUserbundle on my application, I have manage to get chained userproviders to work as well as overriding some of the default controllers.

I have one issue though, I need to find a way to intercept the login process.

My userobject is linked to a client entity, Now I need to deny access to the Userobject even though it's valid because the client entity is disabled.

What I have attempted.

1)I tried extending the SecurityController to no avail, it seems to redirect before executing my code.

2) I tried to set _target_path on my login form to a controller that does the check of the client entity status, This seems to work but after I logout the user using,

```
$this->get('request')->getSession()->invalidate() ;
```

The user is redirected back to the login page but I cannot get a flash message to appear on twig template stating that the client is not active.

Any help or ideas will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to attach a handler to the login and logout process: http://www.reecefowell.com/2011/10/26/redirecting-on-loginlogout-in-symfony2-using-loginhandlers/